# Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND on Vercel with Next.JS and serverless-mysql

Tags: node.js, next.js, vercel

I am using Next.js and in the API side i have write a dummy code to get rows from my database with this library : **serverless-mysql**

I have followed the example on the documentation and on my computer this working very fine, I can connect to the database et get the rows. My Database is on my VPS not on my localhost.

But when i deploy my code on Vercel, and I try to access to /api/hello
In my vercel log I have this error :

```
[GET] /api/hello
{
  error: Error: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND "**.***.**.**"
      at connect (/var/task/node_modules/serverless-mysql/index.js:80:15)
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
      at async Object.query (/var/task/node_modules/serverless-mysql/index.js:182:5)
      at async excuteQuery (/var/task/.next/server/pages/api/hello.js:33:25)
      at async handler (/var/task/.next/server/pages/api/hello.js:59:24)
      at async Object.apiResolver (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/api-utils.js:102:9)
      at async Server.handleApiRequest (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:1064:9)
      at async Object.fn (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:951:37)
      at async Router.execute (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/router.js:222:32)
      at async Server.run (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:1135:29)
}
```

(I have replaced the real Ip showed in the message by "** . *** . ** . **")

My database accept connection from outside because I can access to it on my computer.

I have also correctly configured the .env var in project settings.

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: This error has nothing to do with mysql. It means wherever you run this code, it cannot find the IP address specified on the network.

Comment: @Shadow Ok but Why ? With the same Ip, it's working very fine on my computer :/

Comment: I cannot tell you why, you need to check your network configuration and trace the tcp connections.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to set the environment variables both on your vercel dashboard and your nextjs app.

In your .env file

```
 NEXT_PUBLIC_VERCEL_URL = "http://localhost:3000";
```

In your code, reference the variable

```
export const getBaseUrl = () => {
   if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
      return "http://localhost:3000";
    }

   return process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_VERCEL_URL;
 }
```

You can then execute the utility function anywhere in your code.

On vercel, set the environment variable to VERCEL_URL
[image]